# Arcore 3d coordinate system to 2d screen coordinates

Tags: android, kotlin, arcore

I am developing an  android application that needs to detect collision between 3d Node and 2d object detected by tensorflow lite.To do that tried to transform my node's 3d coordinates to 2d screen coordinates but no success so far. Anyone have any idea how to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Before running all these methods, you should check that [getTrackingState()](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/com/google/ar/core/Camera#getTrackingState-) == TrackingState.TRACKING.

1. You should [obtain projection matrix](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/com/google/ar/core/Camera#getProjectionMatrix-dest-offset-near-far) of AR Camera. I'll name the matrix `proj` afterwards.

Note: in current case `offset` should be 0 (because we need to write values from beginning of the array), `near` and `far` values defines [viewing frustum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viewing_frustum). In a nutshell, it's distance after/behind that objects should be clipped. I usually set `near` to `0.1f`, `far`=`100.0f`.

2. Obtain surfaceView width and height.
   You may override onSurfaceChanged method inside your renderer (which, for sure, should implement `GLSurfaceView.Renderer` interface), then add new fields for width and height to your class and change their values when onSurfaceChanged is called. Like:

```
class Yourrenderer : GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
    private var width: Int = -1
    private var height: Int = -1

...

    override fun onSurfaceChanged(gl: GL10?, width: Int, height: Int) {
        this.width = width
        this.height = height
    }

...

}
```

3. Get pose of your anchor using [getPose() method](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/com/google/ar/core/Anchor#getPose-) and obtain matrix using [Pose.toMatrix method](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/com/google/ar/core/Pose#toMatrix-dest-offset). I'll name the anchor pose as `anchorPose`, and this matrix as `anchorMat` afterwards.
4. Then you need to get convert world-space coordinates into window (2D) coordinate. We implement a [method that's called project](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/api/a00666.html) (from word projection).

```
// Dummy matrix
val model = floatArrayOf(
    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
)

// Anchor pose should be obtained at 4th step
val tX: Float =
    model[0] * anchorPose.tx() + model[4] * anchorPose.ty() + model[8] * anchorPose.tz() + model[12] * 1f
val tY: Float =
    model[1] * anchorPose.tx() + model[5] * anchorPose.ty() + model[9] * anchorPose.tz() + model[13] * 1f
val tZ: Float =
    model[2] * anchorPose.tx() + model[6] * anchorPose.ty() + model[10] * anchorPose.tz() + model[14] * 1f
val tW: Float =
    model[3] * anchorPose.tx() + model[7] * anchorPose.ty() + model[11] * anchorPose.tz() + model[15] * 1f
var tmpX: Float = proj.get(0) * tX + proj.get(4) * tY + proj.get(8) * tZ + proj.get(12) * tW
var tmpY: Float = proj.get(1) * tX + proj.get(5) * tY + proj.get(9) * tZ + proj.get(13) * tW
var tmpZ: Float =
    proj.get(2) * tX + proj.get(6) * tY + proj.get(10) * tZ + proj.get(14) * tW
val tmpW: Float =
    proj.get(3) * tX + proj.get(7) * tY + proj.get(11) * tZ + proj.get(15) * tW
tmpX /= tmpW
tmpY /= tmpW
tmpZ /= tmpW
tmpX = tmpX * 0.5f + 0.5f
tmpY = tmpY * 0.5f + 0.5f
tmpZ = tmpZ * 0.5f + 0.5f
tmpX = tmpX * width + 0.0f // to obtain width and height see third step
tmpY = tmpY * height + 0.0f
```

5. Here is what you wanted! tmpX, tmpY is a window-space coordinates. You may ignore tmpZ.

If you have a lot of math like such as that, you might look to migrate your project to C++, [because there's a popular library, which have implemented most of the necessary math, called GLM](https://github.com/g-truc/glm). It's header-only (which means that size of your compiled app won't increase) and more productive (because it uses C++, which is compiled).